# Placing a shadow over a WindowsFormsHost?

Tags: wpf, winforms, xaml, windowsformshost

I have a WPF grid docked next to a RichTextBox hosted inside a WindowsFormsHost. The grid has a shadow that overlays the WindowsFormsHost, however, it's not showing over the WindowsFormsHost.

Is this a generic issue with hosting Windows Forms controls or is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance.

```
<WindowsFormsHost x:Name="WinFormsHost" Focusable="True" Background="White"/>
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Direction="90" Color="#FFC3C3C3" BlurRadius="15" Opacity="0.2"/>
    </Grid.Effect>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WindowsFormsHost operates at the highest z-index and cannot be overridden. It's an old issue called the "airspace problem". Unfortunately there is no workaround.